# How to plot a point on the circumference of a circle using AppleScript and Illustrator

Tags: applescript, adobe

I need to put a grid of squares inside a circle in Illustrator.  Ive written a script that works for this and gives me the following result

[image]

But the problem I have is that the small areas of the grid (inside the red circles) are no good to me.  What I need to do is to stop both the vertical and horizontal path at the last intersection, whenever the left over part of the path is below a certain size, and replace both those small paths with a single path that extends to a point on the circumference where the radius would hit the circumference if it was drawn through the intersection... I hope that makes some sense.

I'm getting there... the next image shows what I've got to...

[image]

So now the blue circles show the areas where everything seems to be working OK... but the red area is the problem.

And, frankly, I've been trying to figure it out all day and my maths is simply not up to it!  Please help!!!

Here's the code that draws the first points of the vertical lines.

What I thought I should do is try and work out the angle from the origin of the circle to the intersection (arctan opposite/adjacent) and then, using that angle, try to calculate the coordinates for the point where the radius intersects the circumference.

The variables passed in are just the starting coordinates for the line being drawn, the amount left over at the top/bottom of the line beyond the last horizontal junction, and an indicator of whether there is a line at the centre or if the lines are offset (ie an odd or even number of columns/rows).

```
on drawVerticalLine(coX, coY, remainder, myOffset)
--
--ALL lines are drawn from top to bottom
--
--the variable 'shouldMovePoints' indicates if the remainder will result in pieces too small to use
--if true then we will move the first and last points on these lines onto the circumference of the cutting area circle
set shouldMovePoints to false

tell application "Adobe Illustrator"

    --create a new path item
    set lineRef to make new path item in current document with properties {stroked:true, filled:false}

    --start plotting line with topmost path point
    --check if the remainder is too small
    if remainder is greater than 0 and remainder is less than the (globalSize * 0.45) then

        set shouldMovePoints to true
        --adjust the coordintes to place them on the circumference

        set lengthOfOpposite to (coY - gOriginY)
        set lengthOfAdjacent to (coX - gOriginX)

        if lengthOfOpposite is less than 0 then
            set lengthOfOpposite to lengthOfOpposite + remainder
        else
            set lengthOfOpposite to lengthOfOpposite - remainder
        end if

        set oppositeOverAdjacent to lengthOfOpposite / lengthOfAdjacent

        set myAngle to (my inverse_tangent_of(oppositeOverAdjacent))

        set newCoX to gOriginX + (gRadius * (my cosine_of(myAngle)))
        set newCoY to gOriginY + (gRadius * (my sine_of(myAngle)))
        make new path point of lineRef with properties {anchor:{newCoX, newCoY}, left direction:{newCoX, newCoY}, right direction:{newCoX, newCoY}, point type:corner}

    else

        make new path point of lineRef with properties {anchor:{coX, coY}, left direction:{coX, coY}, right direction:{coX, coY}, point type:corner}
    end if
```

I am using some snippets that were recommended by someone to calculate the various trig functions.  I'll post them here but I doubt that they are the problem...

Sine

```
repeat until x ≥ 0 and x < 360
    if x ≥ 360 then
        set x to x - 360
    end if
    if x < 0 then
        set x to x + 360
    end if
end repeat

--convert from degrees to radians
set x to x * (2 * pi) / 360

set answer to 0
set numerator to x
set denominator to 1
set factor to -(x ^ 2)

repeat with i from 3 to 40 by 2
    set answer to answer + numerator / denominator
    set numerator to numerator * factor
    set denominator to denominator * i * (i - 1)
end repeat

return answer
```

Cosine:

```
repeat until x ≥ 0 and x < 360
    if x ≥ 360 then
        set x to x - 360
    end if
    if x < 0 then
        set x to x + 360
    end if
end repeat

--convert from degrees to radians
set x to x * (2 * pi) / 360

set answer to 0
set numerator to 1
set denominator to 1
set factor to -(x ^ 2)

repeat with i from 2 to 40 by 2
    set answer to answer + numerator / denominator
    set numerator to numerator * factor
    set denominator to denominator * i * (i - 1)
end repeat

return answer
```

Inverse Tangent:

```
set complimentFlag to false
if x > 1 or x < -1 then
    set x to 1 / x
    set complimentFlag to true
else if x = 1 then
    return 45.0
end if

set answer to 0
set numerator to x
set denominator to 1
set ratio to x
set factor to -(x ^ 2)

repeat while abs(ratio) > 1.0E-4
    set answer to answer + ratio
    set numerator to numerator * factor
    set denominator to denominator + 2
    set ratio to numerator / denominator
end repeat

--convert from radians to degrees
set answer to answer * 360 / (2 * pi)

if complimentFlag is true then
    set answer to 90 - answer
end if

return answer
```

Abs:

```
    if numericVariable < 0 then
    return -numericVariable
else
    return numericVariable
end if
```

Anyway... that's where I'm at.  I can't figure out why only one of the corners is playing up.  I would have thought if there was a problem then both corners in any quadrant should have issues...

I know that Illustrator doesn't have a normal 'compass' when it comes to plotting circles and rotating... but I've lost my bookmark for that info.  Maybe that's the issue.  But it's probably my maths being pretty crappy.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Regarding your trig functions: you can `set x to x mod 360` to bring `x` into the range `−360 < x < 360`, then use the facts that `sin(x)=−sin(−x)` and `cos(x)=cos(−x)` to do away with the first repeat loop.  Also, as your `atan` function is content with an absolute error within the region of `1e−4`, then your `sin` and `cos` functions are a little overzealous: computing 20 terms of a Taylor expansion yields an  absolute error within `1e−15` (which covers all the digits of a 32-bit real). You can safely half the number of iterations from 40 to 20 to still be within `1e−4`.

Comment: Alternatively: `on sin(x)
run script "Math.sin(" & (x*2*pi/360) & ")" in "JavaScript"
end sin`, etc.

Comment: Before I delve into the actual problem at hand, can I ask where else you've posted this question online ?  I don't wish to put effort into tackling a problem only to find it was already dealt with on another site.  That said, I look forward to tackling this once I hear back from you.

Comment: @CJK Thanks so much for your contribution.  I replaced the sin, cos and atan routines using your suggestion of the JavaScript functions and, Hey Presto! I had two lines going the wrong way, rather than the one.  As soon as there were two errors then I could see where I was going wrong.  No idea what is wrong with the routines (if anything) because I really don't fully understand what they do...  But my issue appears to be resolved (at least the issue with the script... not the issue with my shabby maths!).  Thanks again!